# Retrieving Data from LAN Computer with Secondary Internet-enabled Machine

Tags: networking, lan, bridge, remote-control

So we have a trailer with a lidar instrument (retrieves wind information) whose software stores the data locally onto a Win10 laptop connected via router with no internet access. The trailer is in a location with internet, however switching to this prevents the software from storing data (sampled every 10 seconds).

Is there a way to establish a routine with a secondary machine to access the primary laptop and retrieve the files, and then upload or scp them from my computer at home? Something like:

[image: Diagram]

All ideas and suggestions are welcome, as a solution here would save us hours in commute time and speed up our science.

Comment: what precisely does "switching" on the internet entail, and why do you believe that this will interrupt the flow of data? yes what you describe is likely possible as long as both PCs are on the same LAN, but that should give them both access to the Internet, so I'm curious about the need for it.

Comment: Thanks for the questions Frank. The LAN itself offline and serves to connect the laptop to the lidar through TeamViewer and also transmit data from a GPS receiver with a 192.x address. The internet available at the current location is not strong enough to reliably hold a connection, which is why I'm looking for a solution that could instead transfer the data during the connectivity period.

Comment: my first thought then, is what you need isn't a second PC, but a wireless bridge installed in the place you would put that second PC, and configure it to bridge the Internet connected AP to the wireless router that the data collector PC is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the laptop a second network adapter that's connected
to the internet. This can be an external USB network adapter.

You could then connect to the computer by various means : RDP,
VNC software, FTP or whatever, and access your files that way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea harry. I've looked into windows supporting simultaneous network connections and it looks viable, however the strength of the internet is very feeble at the present trailer location and would not support reliable file transfer. The second machine could be housed closer to the fixed access point with stronger signal is my hope

Comment: You could use the second network adapter to connect to the new computer via a fast local link. The new computer can also have two network adapters, one connected to the laptop and the other to the internet.